# Help out a Swedish learner of English

Tags: grammar

I am Swedish. Does what I have written here make sense? A simple yes or no will suffice. Thanks!

We had been speaking to the most noblest of our coterie here in our village, and I decided to have my people know of their plans to have our town hall a new window, our barn a new door, and our school a new may-pole. No sooner had I told them of this news, already had they arranged a gathering in celebration of it, which I do think of as unnecessary, if not a tad absurd. Most certainly am I left pondering the inadequacy of these offerings, as my speaking with Claud yesterday had me expecting offerings of a more bountiful and generous kind. And it is with a great anger that I feel my duty as priest has me thinking of the unfairness that will now have our people not enough food to last through the winter, and if the foretelling of the Sage is to manifest itself to have us with even less food come winter, famine, death, and darkness shall befall our village, all of which I do believe will have the young prince losing his life to such consequences which need not happen were the nobles have their generosity give us more grain, rice and wheat from their surplus supplies.

Comment: The sense is not too difficult to make out, but the diction is often unidiomatic and occasionally ungrammatical.

Comment: Please do rewrite it, so that I may learn by my mistakes. Thanks.

Comment: I'm afraid that's proofreading, which is [off-topic](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) here.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Please note that the StackExchange Q&A format is very ill-suited to proofreading, and therefore such requests are explicitly [off-topic](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). While I have no firsthand experience with it, [Lang-8](http://lang-8.com/) has been recommended by others..

Comment: Your final hundred-word sentence is magisterial; I am bowled over by the weight of your righteous indignation.

Answer (score 2):

An example that is easy to deal with: "most noblest". The most noble of a group of people who are considered noble is the noblest. There is a progession of nobility from noble to nobler to noblest, just as there is a progression from big to bigger to biggest. "Most" is implied in the term noblest, so "most noble" or "noblest" will work, but not "most noblest". Noblest, like biggest, is called a superlative, and requires no further adjectives.

Another example is "their plans to have our town hall a new window, etc". "Have" makes no sense here, but "give our town hall a new window" or "provide a new window for our town hall" will work. This is complicated by the question of whether you mean they will provide a replacement for an existing window, or to install a window where there was only a blank wall.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it makes sense.  Pretty bad English, but interpretable.

Answer (score 0):

No sooner  X    **than**   Y

> No sooner had I (done A B C ) than they arranged a gathering to...

"have" is dead; try

> ...unfairness that will now leave our people with not enough food...